# How do i fix an error for an unhandled exception?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm getting this error when I click the update button in my form:

> " An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'intGenderID'."

The update does not work.
Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

        Dim strSelect As String = ""
        Dim strFirstName As String = ""
        Dim strLastName As String = ""
        Dim strAddress As String = ""
        Dim strCity As String = ""
        Dim strState As String = ""
        Dim strZip As String = ""
        Dim strPhoneNumber As String = ""
        Dim strEmail As String = ""
        Dim intRowsAffected As Integer

        
        Dim cmdUpdate As OleDb.OleDbCommand

         
        If Validation() = True Then
            ' open database
            If OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer() = False Then

                ' No, warn the user ...
                MessageBox.Show(Me, "Database connection error." & vbNewLine &
                                    "The application will now close.",
                                    Me.Text + " Error",
                                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                
                Me.Close()

            End If

            
            If Validation() = True Then

                strFirstName = txtFirstName.Text
                strLastName = txtLastName.Text
                strAddress = txtAddress.Text
                strCity = txtCity.Text
                strState = txtState.Text
                strZip = txtZip.Text
                strPhoneNumber = txtPhoneNumber.Text
                strEmail = txtEmail.Text



                
                strSelect = "Update TGolfers Set strFirstName = '" & strFirstName & "', " & "strLastName = '" & strLastName &
                "', " & "strAddress = '" & strAddress & "', " & "strCity = '" & strCity & "', " &
                 "strState = '" & strState & "', " & "strZip = '" & strZip & "', " &
                 "strPhoneNumber = '" & strPhoneNumber & "', " & "strEmail = '" & strEmail & "', " &
                 "intShirtSizeID = '" & cboShirtSizes.SelectedValue.ToString & "' " &
                 "intGenderID = '" & cboGenders.SelectedValue.ToString & "' " &
                 "Where intGolferID = " & cboGolfers.SelectedValue.ToString

               

                MessageBox.Show(strSelect)


               
                cmdUpdate = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)

               
                intRowsAffected = cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()

                
                If intRowsAffected = 1 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Update successful")
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Update failed")
                End If

               
                CloseDatabaseConnection()

                
                frmManageGolfers_Load(sender, e)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: That has never been the correct way to build SQL queries in NET.  You have discovered one of the reasons why.  Others are more devastating.  Use SQL parameters. Always.

Comment: You have a Function called OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer , a command typed as OleDb.OleDbCommand and your question is tagged MySql. Which is it? SQL Server, Access, or MySql?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error means that the SQL isn't the right syntax. Its quite strict.

Near 'intGenderID' means the syntax error is just before this. In your case, you've missed a comma.

Comment: OP mark this answer as answer, the software tells you exactly where to fix the problem it says near 'intGenderID'

Answer (score 0):

I will proceed as if this MySql. Keep your database objects local. You need to keep track that they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using blocks take care of this even if there is an error.

Always use parameters. Not only does it make writing the sql statement much easier it will save your database from sql injection.

Additional comments in-line.

```vb
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim intRowsAffected As Integer
    Dim strSelect As String = "Update TGolfers Set strFirstName = @FirstName, strLastName = @LastName, strAddress = @Address, strCity = @City, strState = @State, strZip = @Zip, strPhoneNumber = @Phone, strEmail = @EMail, intShirtSizeID = @ShirtSize, intGenderID = @Gender Where intGolferID = @GolferID;"
    If Not Validation() Then
        'Actually the input should be validated before we get here
        MessageBox.Show("Did not pass validation. Correct the input")
        Return
    End If
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(strSelect, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCity.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@State", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtState.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Zip", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtZip.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPhoneNumber.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMail", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text
            'Are you sure you have set the .ValueMember of the combo boxes?
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ShirtSize", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cboShirtSizes.SelectedValue.ToString
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cboGenders.SelectedValue.ToString
            'Are your sure that intGolferID is not a number
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@GolferID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = cboGolfers.SelectedValue
            cn.Open()
            intRowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
    If intRowsAffected = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Update successful")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Update failed")
    End If
    frmManageGolfers.Show() 'I can't image why you would try to send a button and the button's event args to the Load event of another form
End Sub
```